# How to handle push notification when application is killed

Tags: react-native, push-notification

Pardon me if this question has been asked before, I just couldn't find the answer.

I have an react native application, it has calling feature using .Net Core SignalR (For signalling) and webRTC for actual calling. There are three scenarios out of which my application works fine in two scenarios:

1. Application is in foreground: For this I simply inform other client that X is calling you (using signals from SignalR).
2. Application is in background: For this I send push notification to the client which is read by the application (notification listener) which in turns opens up the call accept/decline window.

I am struggling with scenario 3:

3. Application has been killed (from recent apps etc.) and is now not in background in this scenario I only receive the push notification but call windows doesn't open but if I open up that notification I can see the calling window as intended. I need a solution which will open up the calling window automatically just like it does in scenario 1 & 2. How can I listen to push notifications when the application is dead? So that I can show the call window?

I am  looking for a solution that would preferably work both on Android and iOS and I am using FCM Push notifications. I am also open to solutions other than push notifications as long as they work correctly.

Comment: Hi Danial, im glad that someone raise this issue again. I did some findings earlier without solution found and posted a similar ques, you may again [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64329778/how-to-handle-push-notification-when-app-was-force-quit-by-user-ios).

Answer (score 0):

For supporting to android and iOS  you can use

```
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";


messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => { 
// handle your notification message here 
}
```